# Open second chromium instance on another X11 DISPLAY session

Tags: xorg, chromium

I have bash script which is trying to launch two chromium instances on two different X11 DISPLAYs:

```
DISPLAY=:0 chromium &
DISPLAY=:1 chromium &
```

Unfortunately both instances are launched at `DISPLAY :0` and second chromium says `Opening in existing browser session.`

How to force second chromium to start on `DISPLAY :1` ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/35414/977044